# Rails and OAuth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, bing-api

More of a theoretical question here - how can you get around using OAuth when you don't want to use it, but are using an API that requires it.

For example recently I was looking through the Bing Ads API and noticed they now require you to do OAuth as part of the process. Which makes sense if you're making an application that allows a user to control their Bing Ads account via your app. However, let's say you wanted all of your users to interact with one Bing Ads account.

Is it possible to hardcode all of the OAuth pieces in the background and just use the same authentication for every user to essentially send their stuff to the same Bing Ads account.
- If so, what sort of negative impacts would there be on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is simply not possible to get around using OAuth if the API requires it, OAuth can be used for more than just the "access delegated to client by current user" use case. As you suggest, if you want all users of your app to interact with **your** Bing account ("on your behalf" on OAuth speak), you can certainly do that with OAuth.

For an OAuth 2.0 implementation this would mean that **you** obtain an access token and preferably a refresh token in some way for your app, e.g. by you yourself going once through the Authorization Code flow (also, some services allow you to generate tokens in their web UI). Then you would "hard-configure" the token(s) in your app and use it/them to talk to the Bing API.

If a refresh token is included as well as an access token then your app can get a new access token in the backend whenever the old one expires without you (or your users) having to go through that initial flow again.

Be aware that this is not good practice for mobile apps, where you would have to distribute your app with the tokens embedded in the binary packages. Those tokens could easily be grabbed through hacking/scanning those binaries. But when the tokens are used in a backend service and never exposed in the front end, this is a perfectly valid scenario.

Comment: Ah very interesting. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the detailed explanation!